# Return class or what ever it is

Tags: c#

I want to return `DataReader` from a Function. so i can use it regardless of its is MySQL or MS-SQL?

```
private void Connection(string Command)
{       
    if (DBtype == "MySQL")
    {
        MySqlConnection MysqlConnection1 = new MySqlConnection(CS);
        MySqlCommand MySqlcommand = new MySqlCommand(Command, MysqlConnection1);
        MysqlConnection1.Open();
        MySqlDataReader reader = MySqlcommand.ExecuteReader();
    }
    else
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(CS);
        SqlCommand Sqlcommand = new SqlCommand(Command, sqlConnection1);
        sqlConnection1.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = Sqlcommand.ExecuteReader();
    }  
}
```

Comment: Did you have a look to see if they share a common base class? Hint: They do.

Comment: your best bet is to return http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Try using ODBC (`OdbcConnection`, etc.) - it will unify the databases.

Comment: But why is your method `void` if you want to return something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the return type of your method to be `IDataReader` since both `SqlDataReader` and `MySqlDataReader` implement this interface.

```
private IDataReader Connection(string Command)
{
    IDataReader dataReader = null;

    if (DBtype == "MySQL")
    {
        MySqlConnection MysqlConnection1 = new MySqlConnection(CS);
        MySqlCommand MySqlcommand = new MySqlCommand(Command, MysqlConnection1);
        MysqlConnection1.Open();
        dataReader = MySqlcommand.ExecuteReader();
    }
    else
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(CS);
        SqlCommand Sqlcommand = new SqlCommand(Command, sqlConnection1);
        sqlConnection1.Open();
        dataReader = Sqlcommand.ExecuteReader();
    }  

    return dataReader;
}
```

Furthermore, I think that you should pass as an argument to your `Connection` method the type of the database.

Comment: Yes that works but then i have the problem that IDataReader dossent have .HasRows any nice little solution to that also and then it woudt be gold ?

Comment: @Kaalund one thing that I would give it a go, If I were in your position, it would be using a `while`, `while (dataReader.Read())`. This way you could check if the `dataReader` has rows and in each step of the `while`, while the condition is `true`,`dataReader.Read()==true`, read the current value.